# PHP reset page on refresh

Tags: php, page-refresh

I have a login.php file where I submit a form. When the form has validation errors (eg username, password empty) I create with  echo ''; 
a bootstrap well in order to display the errors. My question is when I refresh the page, I want to have the .well not displayed, as when the page first loads.
Any idea on how this could be done?

Thanks in advance

```
   <?php if(count($msg) > 0) {
    echo '<div class="well">'; 
    echo '<p style="color: red;">Validation Errors</p>';
 } ?>
<?php foreach($msg as $value) {
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>';
    echo $value;
    echo '</li></ul>';
} ?>
<?php echo '</div>'; ?>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: How do you refresh the page?

Comment: Just with pressing F5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use sessions to identify that a request is done by the same user, specially with the same parameters. When you display the error message you save a marker in the session that you have displayed the error message like this:

```
$_SESSION['errorDisplayed'] = true;
```

Use this variable to see if you have show the error message in a previous request like this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['errorDisplayed'])) {
    // not shown the error message yet, so do it here (if there are errors)

    $_SESSION['errorDisplayed'] = true;
}
```

Keep in mind that at some time you have to clear the marker with `unset()` again so you see any error messages again.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a new variable such as `$hasError` and whenever you have validation errors, you set this variable to `true`. Then, in your output, you only print the `.well` class when `$hasError` is false like so:

`<div class="<?=(!$hasError) ? '.well' : '';?>">YOUR MESSAGE HERE!</div>`